# Why is the -i argument to supervisor important to get an interactive shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in order to impersonate as superuser1 I need to run command like this

```
sudo -u superuser1 -i
```

I did try `sudo -u superuser1` which means switch to superuser1 and its totally making sense, but it doesn't work

I also read about the sudo man page -i option

> -i, --login
>   Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry
>   as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such
>   as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is
>   specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c
>   option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
>   sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running
>   the shell. The command is run with an environment similar to the one a
>   user would receive at log in. The Command environment section in the
>   sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment
>   in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

I can see, it puts the command into interactive mode, but it doesn't explain why
`sudo -u superuser1` doesn't work.

can any one explain what exactly -i does, and why without it doesn't work

Comment: Are you saying that `sudo -u superuser1` does _not_ work, but `sudo -u superuser1 -i` works?

Comment: `sudo -u superuser1` doesn't work because you don't tell it what to do. You can specify a command to run like  `sudo -u superuser1 whoami`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is given, explicitly, in the man page content you quoted in the question itself:

> If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

That's behavior specific to `sudo -i`. If you want an interactive shell, then, you need to either run `sudo -i`, or something like `sudo -u user1 -- bash -i -l`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the man page, the -i option, not only puts the command into interactive mode but also execute the content of .profile and presumably .bashrc. I imagine that to run your command you must specify some environment variable that is automatically loaded when you use the "-i" option.

Comment: "Run your command" -- the OP isn't running a command at all, they're wanting an interactive shell. (On account of that, this arguably isn't a valid StackOverflow question at all, since it's about interactive use rather than programming).